# NSMutableArray not adding NSDecimalNumber

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsmutablearray, nsdecimalnumber

I'm trying to add `NSDecimalNumbers` to an `NSMutableArray`. Here is the code:

```
for (int i = 0; i < [dollarArray count]; i++)
{
    NSString *string = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.%@", [[firstArray objectAtIndex:i] firstObject], [[secondArray objectAtIndex:i] firstObject]];
    NSDecimalNumber *number = [NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithString:string];
    [arrData addObject:number];
}
NSLog(@"%@ and %@", number, arrData);
```

The results for `number` is correct - it shows all the numbers. But for `arrData`, it shows `null`. Is it not correct the way I add `decimalNumber` to `arrData`? What should I do to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you initialise `arrData` properly?
`NSMutableArray *arrData = [NSMutableArray new];`

Comment: Oh! How stupid of me! So embarrassing. Thanks for the answer! (Waiting for timer, to accept your answer.)

Comment: @Horray :-), everyone makes init mistakes like this frequently. (Even I do :p)

Comment: @Schemetrical if i have use the same code application get crashed...is firstArray and secondArray is NSArray or NSMutableArray.

Comment: @AshokLondhe `NSMutableArray`: you can add and remove items. `NSArray`: static array

Comment: k. i know this... but if i take NSArray then application get Crashed.

Comment: @AshokLondhe then use `NSMutableArray *array = yourNonMutableArray.mutableCopy;`

Comment: It gives exceptions because of firstObject. and if i removed firstObject application run properly.

Comment: @AshokLondhe because you have no first object...? Check if array.count >= 1 before calling firstObject. If you have further issues, please create a question.